# custom before/after hooks in rails for non standard actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hook

I have a controller with some non standard actions, like admin, moderate, etc. I tried using the hook `before_admin` it that didn't work. Is it possible to use these hooks for my custom actions?

Sorry for the lack of clarity. Say I have something that I want to happen before saving..it's easy to just do a `before_save :do_whatever` inside the model. I want to have something like a `before_admin :do_something` or `before_moderate :do_something`, where these are custom methods in my controller.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't really understand your question at all then. Could you clarify? Example code?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, :do_something is in your controller and you want to use these methods in your model hooks? Isn't that against MVC?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you need a before_filter.

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base 
  before_filter :do_whatever, :only => :admin

  def admin
    # Code for your controller action
  end

  private

  def do_whatever
    # Code that runs before the admin action
  end
end
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more information.

Edit: If you want different controllers/actions to do different things to a model, then the appropriate place to put that logic is in the controller. Proper MVC design keeps the model ignorant of the controller/action that's manipulating it. It may seem inconvenient now, but in the long run it'll go a long way towards keeping your code clean and usable.

Edit again: Sorry, you asked how and not why, and I missed it completely. You'd do:

```
def action
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  @thing.boolean = true
  @thing.save
end
```

Comment: But I don't want to do this in my controller. I can do whatever, but I need to change an attribute of a particular object (the one in question). The only way I know how to do that is when you're inside a certain model.

Basically I just want to always set a boolean in a model depending on what action it just went through.